# IOS App Store Rejection: App name includes text which is not relevant

Tags: ios, iphone, appstore-approval

My IOS App is rejected and the reason provided is-

> From Apple
>
> 2. 3 PERFORMANCE: ACCURATE METADATA
> 3. DESIGN: PREAMBLE
>
> Performance - 2.3
>
> We noticed that your app name to be displayed on the device includes
> the following information, which is not relevant to the app's content
> and functionality:
>
> "IOS"
>
> Next Steps
>
> Please revise or remove this content from your app name to be
> displayed on the device.

Now the issue is- **my App name doesn't consists any text as "IOS"**, but my Bundle-Id is.

So, are they expecting me to change the Bundle-Id?

Also, what is the "Performance - 2.3" -means? Is it a rating?

Sorry for these off-topic queries as this is my first IOS App.

** I have replied to their resolution and asked the same questions, but after 1 day they din't replied yet.

Comment: Maybe it's in the bundle display name?

Comment: my bundle name is- com.XYZApps.myAppIOS. It has IOS at the end.

Comment: That's the Bundle ID, I'm talking about the bundle display name, which is the name that shows under the icon on the home screen.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because app store submission policy is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/65839) and better addressed by [Apple support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/65839).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to always check the Apple Store Review Guidelines.

Here you can find what you need about accurate metadata

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#accurate-metadata

Answer (score 1):

First step you must remove any word contain iOS in your app name or Bundle.

Second step you must set clear description to your app and read carefully APP store review guidelines from [here](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#accurate-metadata). I hope 
I help you.

Answer (score 0):

They are referred to the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#accurate-metadata)

If you really do not have iOS in the title, you could go back to them, as you have, but they do get very touchy about anything which looks like [Apple copyrighted/trademark infringement](http://www.apple.com/legal/intellectual-property/guidelinesfor3rdparties.html).